# How to get posts with 'any' option includes a new post status?

Tags: php, wordpress

I create a new post status called "old" with the code below.

```
    $args = [
        'label' => _x( 'Old', 'page' ),
        'label_count' => _n_noop( 'Old (%s)', 'Old (%s)' ),
        'public' => false,
        'internal' => true,
        'show_in_admin_all_list' => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
    ];

    register_post_status( 'old', $args );
```

When I try to get all post in any status, I couldn't get the posts which is marked as "Old".

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key'    => 'parent_post_id',
    'meta_value'  => 123,
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'post_type'   => 'any',
);
$posts = get_posts( $args ); // posts without "old"
```

If I pass the "Old" as a post_status value with "any" in array, it works.

```
 $args = array(
    'meta_key'    => 'parent_post_id',
    'meta_value'  => 123,
    'post_status' => ['any', 'old'],
    'post_type'   => 'any',
);
$posts = get_posts( $args ); // posts with "old"
```

What should I do to get posts which are marked as "old" with "any" option in Wp Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read [the docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

> 'any' - retrieves any status except those from post statuses with
>   'exclude_from_search' set to true (i.e. trash and auto-draft).

Look at your code:

```
'exclude_from_search' => true,
```

Comment: Check it if it was helpful, please.